# Calculating checksums in the Simple File System

Tags: filesystems, checksum

I am developing a console program for manipulating SFS images. There are many file systems name SFS so to be specific, [this](https://www.d-rift.nl/combuster/vdisk/sfs.html) is the specification I am implementing. However I don't understand how the checksums are calculated.

I have looked at this piece of code for a while and it's pretty obvious that
this is where the checksums are calculated, but I don't understand Basic.

```
' compute checksum
For wl = start + &H1AC To start + &H1BC
    Get ff, wl, wb
    wi = wi + wb
Next wl
wb = (256 - (wi And &HFF)) And &HFF
```

The full source can be found [here](https://www.d-rift.nl/combuster/vdisk/vdisk-source.tar.gz). The snippet is from the "sfs.bas" file and the method is called "format_sfs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is my C# implementation of the checksum method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Calculates the checksum of the given <paramref name="superBlock"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="superBlock">The super block to calculate the checksum from.</param>
/// <returns>The calculated checksum.</returns>
private static byte Checksum(SuperBlock superBlock)
{
    byte[] bytes = Structures.ToBytes(superBlock);

    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0x1AC; i < 0x1BD; i++)
        result += bytes[i];

    return (byte)((256 - (result & 0xFF)) & 0xFF);
}
```